# Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group with $26$ elements. Prove $x^3\neq e$ for all $x\in G\setminus\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group with $26$ elements and $e$ is the neutral element. Prove $x^{3} \neq e$ for all $ x \in G\setminus \{e\}.$

1. If a group has even order there is an element, $a \neq e$ such that $a^{2} = e$.
2. Therefore $x^{2} \cdot x = e \cdot x = x$. Thus $x^{3} \neq e$.

Any suggestions on how else to answer this? I feel like I would have to prove the first statement to answer this way.

Comment: The order of an element must divide the order of the group.

Comment: Your argument only works for the element satisfying $x^2=e$, not all elements.

Comment: This seems like a very direct application of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: If $x^3=e$, then $x^{27} =e$. Since  $x^{26} =e$, we get $x=e$

Comment: Why is this downvoted? There is an attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x\in G$ is nontrivial such that $x^3=e$. Then $H=\{e, x, x^2\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ and so, by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), we have

$$3=\lvert H\rvert\mid\lvert G\rvert =26,$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Can you show how H is a subgroup? I drew a Cayley table to help visualize it but I'm having a hard time understanding how $x^{3}=e$ means you get H.

Comment: @bgschool: It is the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$. Its Cayley table is $$\begin{array}{c|ccc} \times & e & x & x^2\\ \hline e & e & x & x^2\\ x & x & x^2 & e\\ x^2 & x^2 & e & x\end{array}.$$

Comment: Since $H$ is finite, @bgschool, it suffices to show that $H$ is closed.

Comment: Does that answer your question, @bgschool? Please don't forget to accept this, if so, by clicking the checkmark $\checkmark$ next to it.

Comment: Why the downvote?